# What are the errors of this Java code?

Tags: java

```
package example;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Object;

public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        // Write the object out to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(oldObj);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
        // a copy of the object back in.
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        obj = in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}

public class mytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        clone

    }
}
```

For above code, it wants to show the deep copy of Java. But myeclipse reports some errors. But I don't know what is wrong with it?
Could anyone please help to point them out?

[image]

**Changed the code according to your suggestion.**

```
package example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.Object;

class Utils {
    public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            // Write the object out to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(oldObj);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
            // a copy of the object back in.
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

public class mytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object clonedObject = Utils.copy(new Object());
        clonedObject.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

**Further:**
Thank you all!
I modifeid the code like above, it becomes better but still cannot run normally.
The new error message is below:
[image]

Any new suggestion?

Comment: You must put that method inside a class.

Comment: No class.. so it's not valid

Comment: put `public class mytest {` on line 11

Comment: Hey Tom, looks like you forgot to define the class. Rename your file to MyTest.java and then define MyTest class inside the document. This link will help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Really, this is basic Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have floating methods in Java. Everything must be a member of a class. In this instance, a dummy class with only static methods called `Utils` would be common practice.

e.g.

```
public class Utils {

    // Static methods go here
    public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
        // etc
    }

}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
public class mytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object clonedObject = Utils.copy(new Object());
        // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following steps to  solve your errors:

1. Make a package inside a Project(Specific Name)
2. Inside a created package make a name `MyTest`.
3. Write or copy the method into that class which has been created
   above.
4. To Run the Program Make one main Method any call it by there name if
   it is static.
5. If your method is not static  make a object of the class and call by
   that object of the class.
6. It will solve your Error &  also run your program...

**Note:**  Try to put `finally`  block to free the resources like object, `ByteArrayOutputStream` & `ObjectStream` etc....  It will increase your performance of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a method into a class.

```
public class SomeClass{
public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        // Write the object out to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(oldObj);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
        // a copy of the object back in.
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        obj = in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;



}
```

And you can use it as:

```
public class mytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Object object = Someclass.copy(someObject);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare methods (even static ones) outside of a class in Java. You would have to put everything (except the imports) inside a class.

You'll need something like:

```
public class YourClass {
    public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `public static Object copy(Object oldObj)` isn't located in a class. That's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a class named `mytest` as the 'top level scope' of this file, nest all other methods in it.

```
class mytest { 
   public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
       Object obj = null;
       try {
           // Write the object out to a byte array
           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
           out.writeObject(oldObj);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

           // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
           // a copy of the object back in.
           ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
           ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
           obj = in.readObject();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();   
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
           cnfe.printStackTrace();
       }
       return obj;
   }

   public class mytest {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           clone

       }
   }
}
```

As a side note, you should rename the class name (and file name) to `MyTest` and `MyTest.java` - to match the java coding convention.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your method in a class, preferably called `mytest` since it's the name of the file, declared like

```
public class mytest {
    //Your method here
}
```

Also note that the naming convention in Java is to have class names starting with a capital letter, so it would be `MyTest`, and your file should be renamed to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class MyTest {

public static Object copy(Object oldObj) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        // Write the object out to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(oldObj);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
        // a copy of the object back in.
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        obj = in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        clone

    }
}
```

There are no methods who do not belong to a class (like a JavaScript-Function).
Static means that the method does belong to the class and not to an instance of the class as a non static method would do

Comment: classname should start with capital-letter

Answer (score 0):

You can't write methods outside the class. Put your method `#copy` inside the class. like this:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class mytest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // Now you can use your method here
    }

    public static Object copy(Object oldObj) 
    {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            // Write the object out to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(oldObj);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Retrieve an input stream from the byte array and read
            // a copy of the object back in.
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `class` here? these `method` should contain a class.

Your java class should looks like this

```
 package name;

 imports;

 public class MyClass{

   public void myMethod(){

   }

 }
```